# Example of embedded Jetty and using Micrometer for stats (without Spring)

Tags: jetty, micrometer

I am new to using Micrometer as a metrics/stats producer and I am having a hard time in getting it configured correctly with my Jersey/Embedded Jetty server. I would like to get Jetty statistics added.

I already have the servlet producing stats for the JVM in a Prometheus format.

Does anyone know of a good working example on how to configure it?

I am not using SpringBoot.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to look at the Spring Boot code. For example it [binds the jetty connections](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/jetty/JettyConnectionMetricsBinder.java#L49)

```java
JettyConnectionMetrics.addToAllConnectors(server, this.meterRegistry, this.tags);
```

And it uses an `ApplicationStartedEvent` to [find the server reference](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/jetty/AbstractJettyMetricsBinder.java#L37).

```java
private Server findServer(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    if (applicationContext instanceof WebServerApplicationContext) {
        WebServer webServer = ((WebServerApplicationContext) applicationContext).getWebServer();
        if (webServer instanceof JettyWebServer) {
            return ((JettyWebServer) webServer).getServer();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

There are other classes that record the thread usage and SSL handshake metrics.